# python yotube api постоянный запрос на авторизацию

Tags: python, youtube-api

Проблема в том что каждый раз приходиться переходить по ссылке

> Please visit this URL to authorize this application: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=14302665606-o3rfc3qbf7jc1o2hg73igdtmgkirha0j.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyt-analytics.readonly&state=M8YpSMIXTY6a58siJkm1ae1ag2dLYH&code_challenge=8IOFifgv4uJZTmj98vvMvVGNYLc73NlT16RrY_LjwjQ&access_type=offline&prompt=consent&code_challenge_method=S256
>   Enter the authorization code:

которая появляется в консоли подтверждать разрешение на получение аналитики(статистики)
можно это как то отключить чтобы сразу приходил ответ?
вот код :

```
import os
import google.oauth2.credentials
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly']

API_SERVICE_NAME = 'youtubeAnalytics'
API_VERSION = 'v2'
CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client.json"
def get_service():
  flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, SCOPES)
  credentials = flow.run_console()
  return build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials = credentials)

def execute_api_request(client_library_function, **kwargs):
  response = client_library_function(
    **kwargs
  ).execute()

  print(response)

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

if __name__ == '__main__':
  # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPs verification when running locally.
  # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled when running in production.
  os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'
  youtubeAnalytics = get_service()
  execute_api_request(
      youtubeAnalytics.reports().query,
      ids='channel==MINE',
      startDate='2017-01-01',
      endDate='2019-12-31',
      metrics='estimatedMinutesWatched,views,likes,subscribersGained,comments',
      dimensions='day',
      sort='day'
  )`
```

Comment: Вам нужен сервисный аккаунт, посмотрите, здесь обсуждается подробный вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46457093/google-drive-api-with-python-from-serverbackend-without-browser-autentication/47524127

Comment: Или еще тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36710392/youtube-api-avoid-authentication-screen-in-browser